# Creating an algorithm for passwords in php?

Tags: php, algorithm, encryption, passwords, cryptography

i would like to create my own algorithm for passwords which will be stored for a user login. I am trying to avoid using md5, sha1, etc as i would like to learn to do it myself, however i do not know were to start. My question is how and what is the best way to do this?thank you

Comment: If you are planning on creating your own encryption, you better REALLY understand encryption and how to write secure encryption algorithm before putting anything into production.  IMO, outside of this being an academic exercise you would be better off in a production application using a proven encryption technique.

Comment: What do you mean by "algorithm for passwords which will be stored"? Are you talking about hashing the passwords to store them, or something to generate strong passwords? If the former, answer is simple - **DON'T**.

Comment: If you really want to learn it yourself I can highly recommend getting a copy of [Bruce Schneier's 'Applied Cryptography'](http://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html). This is a wonderful book but be warned, it ain't easy! This is why people use off-the-shelf algorithms such as md5 etc.

Comment: @PeteH please don't hash using MD5 =o\

Comment: Tip: Don't do it! Here's a talk I gave on password hashing in PHP: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNdW5HWBhG0)

Comment: [Schneier's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Schneier#Cryptography)

Comment: @PeteH MD5 is weak and is used for hashing, and should not be used for storing passwords. Using bcrypt is much safer.

Comment: @crypticツ - please read my original comment more closely. I suggested a book the guy can go read if he wants to learn about cryptography. I did not comment on the merits or otherwise of any particular algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

[Don't roll your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own).

[Use bcrypt for passwords](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).

Answer (score 0):

Get a good book on cryptography if you really want to learn and try yourself how to perform those algorithms yourself. So that you can get the idea of how cryptography works.

Then try to implement using PHP.

But one thing, why reinvent the wheel when you can get already written libraries for encryption that are all well written.

And also it would be very tedious to write one yourself and you may face many problems like performance,security,etc.